# Why are some of my files being replicated?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm running a django framework and notice that when I'm editing a file I will get another file in the form "filename.extension~". What exactly is that "~" doing there and why am I generating another file?

If it's a temp file, when does it go away?

Comment: Many text editors do this. Nothing django specific. For example if you open MS Word, and you can see hidden files, you will see a copy of the file in the same directory. It is a security measure for crashing etc. EDIT: What [he](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112315/why-are-some-of-my-files-being-replicated/7112366#7112366) said.

Comment: This is not a programming question, it belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple misunderstanding, not about programming or tools used primarily for programming.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a temp file created by your editor to support restoring if you crash/forget to save/etc.  I'm sure if I googled a bit I'd even be able to figure out which editor(s) use that format for their temp files.

Has nothing to do with django.

Comment: I know I've seen gvim use tildes in the filenames.

Comment: I don't know I just use normal old vim and it uses .filename.extension.swp for it's tmp files

Comment: thanks. when does the tmp file go away?

Comment: That would depend on your editor.  Most will go away when you cleanly close the editor

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with django, but I'm sure it's a temporary/backup file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary file created by your editor - specifically, these are created by [`gedit`](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/), the default editor in Gnome.

I use GVIM, which creates files of the format `.filename.swp`. As others have said, many editors have similar techniques; if they didn't create files like this they might well create files in `/tmp`. These files are useful places to store copies of your document should the editor crash, allowing the editor to recover the file. The existence of a file `.something.swp` means that when vim opens `something` it offers to recover it, for example.

Sometimes these temporary files are not cleaned up by editors, in which case you can do it yourself recursively across your project:

```
find . -name "*~" -exec rm {} \;
```

To see what this affects, use `find . -name "*~"` on its own.